# Selenium get() redirects to another url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to navigate to the following page and extract the html https://www.automobile.it/annunci?b=data&d=DESC, but everytime i call the `get()` method it looks like the website redirects me to the another page, always the same one which is https://www.automobile.it/torrenova?radius=100&b=data&d=DESC.

here's the simple code i'm running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ex_path)
driver.get("https://www.automobile.it/annunci?b=data&d=DESC")
html=driver.page_source
```

if i do the same thing using the request module i don't get redirected

```
import requests
html=requests.get("https://www.automobile.it/annunci?b=data&d=DESC")
```

i don't understand why it's behaving like this, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a cookie is impacting your crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can clear browser cache by using the below code :

I am assuming that you are using chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ex_path)
driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.get("https://www.automobile.it/annunci?b=data&d=DESC")
```

Comment: it throws the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`
I had to set waits explicitly as follows `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`
`button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//settings-ui")`
`driver.implicitly_wait(10)`
`ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()`

Still i get redirected to the second URL

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.delete_all_cookies()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ex_path)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("https://www.automobile.it/annunci?b=data&d=DESC")
html=driver.page_source
```

PS: be also warned: Page_source will not get you the completed DOM as rendered.

Comment: with `driver.delete_all_cookies()` the behavior changed to URL-->redirect URL2-->redirect URL, it still goes through the redirection but it lands back to the correct URL, i was wondering if you had any ideas why this is happening, i want to test a little bit more but i'm afraid this workaround could be unstable.
Also i posted just a snippet of the full code, i then pass the html to `BeautifulSoup` to further process it, the only thing i need is that `html=driver.page_source` returns the same html as `requests.get`

Comment: requests.get might not be handling the redirects. What is the status code?

Comment: The redirects might be the proper operation of the SUT. I can't verify that on their end.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't notice i duplicated the same command that's why it did URL-->URL2-->URL, if i just keep your line of codes it doesn't work as intended it still redirects to URL2. The status code for the `request.get()` is  `200`. What is SUT? i tried to google it but couldn't find the meaning. I really need to find a way to avoid redirecting to other part of the sites...